# How to block aceess to a HTTPS site using python-iptables

Tags: python, https, firewall, iptables

I want to implement a simple firewall using python which will block the access to a given list of sites. To do this I want to know how to block a specific site using python-iptables. For example how to block the access to www.facebook.com?

Comment: You want to block access to websites on your own client machine?

Comment: @jonathon Yes. I want to block access to websites on my own machine.

Answer (score 0):

Try this [link](http://www.addictivetips.com/ubuntu-linux-tips/how-to-block-unwanted-website-in-ubuntu-linux/), it works perfect, use subprocess and say block.

or you can also use iptables as well

iptables -A OUTPUT -d www.facebook.com -j DROP

Comment: iptable method doesn't work. It adds line 
1    DROP       all  --  0.0.0.0/0            31.13.81.128
to the Chain OUTPUT. But site is accessible.